# Datatables Checkbox Multi Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using datatables v1.10 and i'm offering the user a number of select boxes in order to filter results. I want to filter the contents a specific column depending on their selection.

I'm building an inventory of volunteers that is searchable and discoverable by the local community.

They need to be able to filter on single and multiple values. So if they select `Collection` the table should display only results containing `Collection`. If they select `Collection` **and** `Cleaning` the table should display only results containing `Collection` **and** `Cleaning` (not `Delivery`). etc.

Currently my table only filters based on a single selection.

[Here's a fiddle](https://codepen.io/johnny_s/pen/MWwZwMz). Code also below;

Suggestions would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      full_name: "Andrea Ragg",
      email: "aragg0@netlog.com",
      telephone: "584-78-0505",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      full_name: "Thornton Keeri",
      email: "tkeeri1@imageshack.us",
      telephone: "503-58-8194",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      full_name: "Reuven Beddis",
      email: "rbeddis2@china.com.cn",
      telephone: "412-16-2320",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Delivery, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      full_name: "Phil Bardwall",
      email: "pbardwall3@phpbb.com",
      telephone: "864-82-5385",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      full_name: "Torey Jefford",
      email: "tjefford4@seesaa.net",
      telephone: "879-42-9577",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      full_name: "Chandler Robe",
      email: "crobe5@biblegateway.com",
      telephone: "299-07-6714",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      full_name: "Rollie Boorn",
      email: "rboorn6@g.co",
      telephone: "358-94-3758",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      full_name: "Andie Daulton",
      email: "adaulton7@nydailynews.com",
      telephone: "776-32-4779",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      full_name: "Andonis Knagges",
      email: "aknagges8@live.com",
      telephone: "879-70-4074",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      full_name: "Marney Moreinis",
      email: "mmoreinis9@jalbum.net",
      telephone: "324-76-8540",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      full_name: "Jean Drayson",
      email: "jdraysona@biglobe.ne.jp",
      telephone: "741-85-8028",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection, Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      full_name: "Rhea Troubridge",
      email: "rtroubridgeb@theguardian.com",
      telephone: "342-47-7173",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      full_name: "Cord Habergham",
      email: "chaberghamc@columbia.edu",
      telephone: "400-95-9506",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Cleaning, Delivery, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      full_name: "Otha Hiers",
      email: "ohiersd@facebook.com",
      telephone: "697-07-9372",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      full_name: "Edna Barg",
      email: "ebarge@wix.com",
      telephone: "210-66-2867",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection, Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      full_name: "Rozalin Wilmut",
      email: "rwilmutf@freewebs.com",
      telephone: "732-74-0848",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 17,
      full_name: "Glen Darben",
      email: "gdarbeng@google.com.au",
      telephone: "570-01-5383",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection, Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 18,
      full_name: "Wally Longstaff",
      email: "wlongstaffh@reference.com",
      telephone: "278-18-3965",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 19,
      full_name: "Moise Murrhardt",
      email: "mmurrhardti@t.co",
      telephone: "165-08-4136",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Delivery, Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 20,
      full_name: "Gloria Tedder",
      email: "gtedderj@ucoz.ru",
      telephone: "809-19-8763",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Delivery, Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      full_name: "Marthena Pavel",
      email: "mpavelk@state.tx.us",
      telephone: "180-16-5508",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 22,
      full_name: "Livvy Tesoe",
      email: "ltesoel@timesonline.co.uk",
      telephone: "748-54-7269",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 23,
      full_name: "Angelle Tondeur",
      email: "atondeurm@ebay.com",
      telephone: "761-27-3445",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 24,
      full_name: "Marsiella Van Schafflaer",
      email: "mvann@europa.eu",
      telephone: "330-85-4309",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Delivery, Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 25,
      full_name: "Norene Pettegree",
      email: "npettegreeo@marketwatch.com",
      telephone: "324-47-1541",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 26,
      full_name: "Gay Newcome",
      email: "gnewcomep@free.fr",
      telephone: "633-37-5490",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Delivery, Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 27,
      full_name: "Karrah Peltzer",
      email: "kpeltzerq@alibaba.com",
      telephone: "785-01-1150",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 28,
      full_name: "Corrinne Gilli",
      email: "cgillir@4shared.com",
      telephone: "390-05-7538",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 29,
      full_name: "Jaymee Townrow",
      email: "jtownrows@walmart.com",
      telephone: "561-19-2949",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 30,
      full_name: "Sarita Siggs",
      email: "ssiggst@berkeley.edu",
      telephone: "272-85-9311",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery, Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 31,
      full_name: "Crissie Connerry",
      email: "cconnerryu@bbb.org",
      telephone: "429-41-7759",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 32,
      full_name: "Pincus Olyfant",
      email: "polyfantv@flickr.com",
      telephone: "554-04-4124",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 33,
      full_name: "Joela Spearett",
      email: "jspearettw@slashdot.org",
      telephone: "249-42-3733",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 34,
      full_name: "Teodora Floyd",
      email: "tfloydx@pcworld.com",
      telephone: "867-72-6127",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 35,
      full_name: "Sherrie Minall",
      email: "sminally@google.co.uk",
      telephone: "698-47-8076",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 36,
      full_name: "Ikey Sowerby",
      email: "isowerbyz@washingtonpost.com",
      telephone: "428-82-5186",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 37,
      full_name: "Dasie Skelhorn",
      email: "dskelhorn10@trellian.com",
      telephone: "804-03-0371",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Delivery, Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 38,
      full_name: "Wilburt Pickard",
      email: "wpickard11@edublogs.org",
      telephone: "130-53-6389",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 39,
      full_name: "Marven Poutress",
      email: "mpoutress12@joomla.org",
      telephone: "630-06-8139",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning, Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 40,
      full_name: "Sheff Ruck",
      email: "sruck13@vinaora.com",
      telephone: "132-51-1884",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 41,
      full_name: "Hyacinth Botcherby",
      email: "hbotcherby14@toplist.cz",
      telephone: "861-11-1370",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 42,
      full_name: "Renato Jouhan",
      email: "rjouhan15@yahoo.com",
      telephone: "616-39-1823",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery, Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 43,
      full_name: "Fayth Alwin",
      email: "falwin16@unc.edu",
      telephone: "887-35-7269",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Delivery, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 44,
      full_name: "Hadrian Gatlin",
      email: "hgatlin17@biblegateway.com",
      telephone: "615-44-7488",
      location: "Dublin",
      service: "Delivery, Collection, Cleaning",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 45,
      full_name: "Rois Fife",
      email: "rfife18@deviantart.com",
      telephone: "655-09-6453",
      location: "Galway",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 46,
      full_name: "Pavlov Pactat",
      email: "ppactat19@nature.com",
      telephone: "261-25-9415",
      location: "Cork",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 47,
      full_name: "Brocky Burnell",
      email: "bburnell1a@blinklist.com",
      telephone: "644-47-6112",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery, Cleaning, Collection",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 48,
      full_name: "Naoma Brimson",
      email: "nbrimson1b@elpais.com",
      telephone: "751-85-9640",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 0
    },
    {
      id: 49,
      full_name: "Valma Reddoch",
      email: "vreddoch1c@buzzfeed.com",
      telephone: "110-89-6953",
      location: "Derry",
      service: "Collection, Delivery, Cleaning",
      availability: 1
    },
    {
      id: 50,
      full_name: "Ebony Kilsby",
      email: "ekilsby1d@engadget.com",
      telephone: "604-37-4930",
      location: "Belfast",
      service: "Delivery",
      availability: 1
    }
  ];

  dataTable = $("#example").DataTable({
    data: data,
    responsive: true,
    //dom: '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
    language: {
      searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "full_name" },
      { data: "email" },
      { data: "telephone" },
      { data: "location" },
      { data: "service" },
      {
        data: "availability",
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data === 0) {
            return '<span class="badge badge-secondary">busy</span>'
;
          }
          if (data === 1) {
            return '<span class="badge badge-success">available</span>'
;
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [0, 2, 3, 5],
        orderable: false
      }
    ]
  });
  $('.filter-checkbox').on('change', function(e){
      var searchTerms = []
      $.each($('.filter-checkbox'), function(i,elem){
        if($(elem).prop('checked')){
          searchTerms.push("^" + $(this).val() + "$")
        }
      })
      dataTable.column(5).search(searchTerms.join('|'), true, false, true).draw();
    });
});
```

```css
.filter-checkbox{
  margin-left: 30px
}
.filter-checkbox:first-child{
  margin-left:0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col py-3 text-center">
      <h2>Community Connect</h2>
       <p class="lead text-muted">Table will filter as you type.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="filter-wrapper">
       <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="collection"/> Collection
       <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="delivery"/>  Delivery
       <input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="cleaning"/>  Cleaning
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col py-3">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Service Offered</th>
            <th>Availability</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add hidden columns for each checkbox value with something as simple as a true/false in that column. Then you can have each checkbox filter against their column and set the value to filter by based on whether the checkbox is checked. While you adding more columns, it makes the filtering simple.

A more complex solution is to use a multi-select on a single column, likely hidden, and dynamically build a regex to filter the column. I use this for a dynamic multi-select option list, but since your options seem static, the hidden columns seems like an easier approach.

Comment: I've been using datatables for several years now and heavily used their (now) legacy api. The newer version might offer a better way, but I'm more used to the legacy way of working with datatables.

Comment: I think I understand your requirement better now, it's limiting to only records that are checked. So if the user selects Collection, then the record returned must only have Collection in there. My suggestion will not work for you then, it was assuming Or's.